# Symfony forms: problemas para duplicar formulario dentro de una colección a partir de su prototype

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

Intento diseñar un formulario para crear filtros de búsqueda, para ellos tengo una clase formulario denominada `CustomReportType` que contiene una colección de formularios de tipo `FilterGroupType` y cada elemento de esta colección puede contener a su vez una coleccion de formularios de tipo `FilterType`.

En el controller inicializo un formulario de tipo CustomReportType con al menos una colección de FilterGroupType y a la vez, esta colección, contiene un formulario de tipo FilterType. En este aspecto no tengo problemas:

```
#[Route('/new', name: 'nuevo')]
    public function new(Request $request): Response {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            try {
                
                $em=$this->manager->getManager();
                
                $customReport = new CustomReport();
                $customReport->setUsuario($this->getUser());
                $customReport->setStartDate(new DateTime('now'));
                $customReport->setEndDate(new DateTime('+ 1 days'));

                $defaultGroup = new FilterGroup();
                $defaultFilterInDefaultGroup = new Filter();
                $em->persist($defaultFilterInDefaultGroup);
                $defaultGroup->addFilterToCollection($defaultFilterInDefaultGroup);
                $em->persist($defaultGroup);
                
                $customReport->addFiltersGroupToCollection($defaultGroup);

                $customReportForm = $this->createForm(CustomReportType::class, $customReport, [
                    'action' => $this->generateUrl('app_reportesPersonalizados_nuevo')
                ]);

                if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
                    $customReportForm->handleRequest($request);
                           // persist logic
                }

                return $this->render('reporte_personalizado/customReportForm.html.twig', ['form' => $customReportForm->createView()]);
            } catch (Exception $exc) {
                $this->logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));
                return new Response($exc->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado");
        }
    }
```

Genera el siguiente formulario:

**Actualización:**
El código de la vista (customReportForm.html.twig). He variado el javascript teniendo en cuenta que la forma en que me ha funcionado es, al agregar el nuevo formulario de la primera colección, obligatoriamente he tenido que cargar el prototype de sus formularios hijos, y agregarle un nuevo formulario hijo a la nueva coleccion. Me llama la atención que ***si el prototype de la colección de formularios FilterGroupType ya contiene el código de un primer formulario para su coleccion FilterType, por qué hay que crear un formulario FilterType y agregárselo al nuevo formulario FilterGroupType??***

```
{% use 'Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}

{% macro filters_prototype(filter, index) %}
    <div class='border mb-1 p-1 filter'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">{{ form_widget(filter.fieldname) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">{{ form_widget(filter.operator) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">{{ form_widget(filter.valueOne) }}</div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12">{{ form_widget(filter.connector) }}</div>
            <div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 colFilterButtons flex'>
                <a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat addFilter'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat removeFilter'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro filterGroup_prototype(filterGroup, index) %}
    <div class="p-1 border text-sm filterGroup mb-1">       
        <div class="row mt-1 mb-1 ml-1 mr-1">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m-1 filtersCollectionContainer" data-prototype='{{ _self.filters_prototype(filterGroup.filtersCollection.vars.prototype)|escape('html_attr') }}'>
                {% for filter in  filterGroup.filtersCollection %}
                    {{ _self.filters_prototype(filter, loop.index) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>                                
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-1">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center">
                {{ form_widget(filterGroup.groupConnector) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-xs text-right colFilterGroupButtons">
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat rounded addFilterGroup" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>&nbsp;
                <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat rounded removeFilterGroup" href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{{ form_start(form, {'attr':{'class':'text-sm', 'id':'custom_report_form'}}) }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-1">
    <div id="filterGroupsContainer" data-index="1" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-1" data-prototype="{{ _self.filterGroup_prototype(form.filtersGroupsCollection.vars.prototype)|escape('html') }}">
        {% for filterGroup in form.filtersGroupsCollection %}
            {{ _self.filterGroup_prototype(filterGroup, loop.index ) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        /**
         * Get groups collections container
         */
        var filterGroupsHolder = $('#filterGroupsContainer');

        /**
         * Add filter group row on button click if 'AND' or 'OR' is selected in SELECT connector of the group
         */
        filterGroupsHolder.on('click', '.addFilterGroup', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#btnSalvar').hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            var filterGroupSelected = $(this).parents('.filterGroup');
            var _choiceSelected = filterGroupSelected.find('.groupConnector').val();
            if (('AND' === _choiceSelected) || ('OR' === _choiceSelected)) {

                /**
                 * Get current index (length) of FilterGroup collection
                 */
                var indexOfFilterGroups = filterGroupsHolder.children().length;

                /**
                 * Get prototype of entire FilterGroup form
                 */
                var filterGroupPrototype = filterGroupsHolder.data('prototype');

                /**
                 * Assign next index for new FilterGroup and create a form template
                 */
                filterGroupPrototype = filterGroupPrototype.replace(/__filterGroups__/g, indexOfFilterGroups);
                var newFilterGroupForm = filterGroupPrototype;

                /**
                 * Append new FilterGroup form to a collection
                 */
                filterGroupsHolder.append(newFilterGroupForm);

                /**
                 * Get newer FilterGroup created
                 */
                var newFilterGroup = filterGroupsHolder.find('.filterGroup:last');
                /**
                 * Get her filters collection
                 */
                var filtersCollectionHolder = newFilterGroup.find('.filtersCollectionContainer:first');

                var filterPrototype = filtersCollectionHolder.data('prototype');

                var filterForm = filterPrototype.replace(/__filters__/g, filtersCollectionHolder.children().length);

                filtersCollectionHolder.append(filterForm);

            } else {
                console.log('No se creal el grupo. No se seleccionó un conector de grupos.');
                return;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Remove filter group row on button click
         */
        filterGroupsHolder.on('click', '.removeFilterGroup', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#btnSalvar').hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            let count = filterGroupsHolder.children().length;

            if (count > 1) {
                var filterGroup = $(this).parents('.filterGroup');
                filterGroup.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }


        });

        filterGroupsHolder.on('click', '.addFilter', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#btnSalvar').hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            var filterSelected = $(this).parents('.filter');
            var filtersCollectionHolder = filterSelected.parents('.filtersCollectionContainer:first');

            var filterPrototype = filtersCollectionHolder.data('prototype');
            var newFilterForm = filterPrototype.replace(/__filters__/g, filtersCollectionHolder.children().length);

            filtersCollectionHolder.append(newFilterForm);
        });

        filterGroupsHolder.on('click', '.removeFilter', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#btnSalvar').hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            var filterSelected = $(this).parents('.filter');
            var filterCollectionHolder = filterSelected.parents('.filtersCollectionContainer:first');
            if (filterCollectionHolder.children().length > 1) {
                filterSelected.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            } else {
                console.info('Solo existe 1 filtro en la coleccion actual. no es posible quitarlo.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```